# find COUNT using LIKE from an inner query without JOIN

Tags: sql

so im trying to generate a listing of artists in a table & lookup the total matches within all rows of a different table that are like the name, not exact. i cant join the tables cause they dont have a col to join on.

when i run the inner query with a preset artist name it returns the correct count.
however, running as an inner query it always returns 0 for the count.

just curious if someone knows how i can do this using sql, or if it can even be done. otherwise i can figure it out with some looping. here is an example of what im doing:

```
SELECT ar.name, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM audio au WHERE au.artist LIKE('%'+ar.name+'%')) AS count
FROM artist ar
ORDER BY ar.name ASC;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT ar.name, count(*) as count
FROM artist ar, audio au
WHERE au.artist LIKE('%'+ar.name+'%'))
GROUP BY ar.name
```

Answer (score 0):

This what you are looking for?

```
SELECT ar.name, count(*) as count
FROM artist ar, audio au
WHERE (ar.artist like '%'+ar.name+'%')
Group by ar.Name
ORDER BY ar.name ASC;
```